# Teradata SQL Tuning : What was the purpose of the below code

Tags: sql, teradata, database-performance, query-performance, sqlperformance

I tuned a query that was badly skewed written by a Teradata Co. Consultant few years back. The same  code was a perpetually high CPU report and it has gotten  worse

```
    SELECT 
    c.child  ,
    a.username ,
    CAST( SUM((((a.AmpCPUTime(DEC(18,3)))+
         ZEROIFNULL(a.ParserCPUTime)) )) AS DECIMAL(18,3)) 
   FROM pdcrinfo.dbqlogtbl a
          LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT queryid,logdate,
        MIN (objectdatabasename) AS                  objectdatabasename
        FROM pdcrinfo.dbqlobjtbl_hst
        GROUP BY 1,2 ) b                  ON a.queryid=b.queryid 
          JOIN dbc.children c   ON b.objectdatabasename=c.child
    WHERE c.parent ='FINDB'
AND  a.logdate BETWEEN                    '2015-12-01'  AND '2015-12-31'
        and    b.logdate BETWEEN                   '2015-12-01'  AND '2015-12-31'
    GROUP BY 1,
        2,
        3
    ORDER BY 1,
        2,
        3;
```

I already rewrote the query joining log & obj tables which have the same PI and then doing an exists on the  dbc.child table and it runs fabulously - same o/p. 
But I thought I got lucky just because FINDB does not have any children that are view databases . 
My question : 
I am trying to understand what is the purpose of 
MIN (objectdatabasename) 
Most of our table database names precede view database names ( which are of the form findb_vw etc ) and so I think he may have tried to eliminate view databases ?
The other thing : Why LOJ ( I changed to IJ ) because you want a value for Objectdatabasename  . I think LOJ does not apply here

I am not sure so throwing the question open on the stage. So just to clarify - I am not looking for tuning tips. I wanted other perspectives on  the   MIN ( Objectdatabasename ) code .

Comment: This should be an example of how **not** to format your code. It's unreadable for me, could you please take some time to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the Left Join is useless (but the optimizer will change it to an Inner Join anyway, so it's just confusing).

The `MIN (objectdatabasename)` was probably used to avoid multiple rows for the same queryid resulting in duplicate rows (and maybe to remove the view dbs).

But IMHO the main reason for bad performance is a missing join condition between the DBQL tables. The tables in `pdcrinfo` should be partitioned by `LogDate` and you need to add `AND a.LogDate=b.LogDate` to the existing `ON a.queryid=b.queryid` to get a fast join (PI + partitioning), otherwise the optimizer must do some kind of preparation or a more expensive *sliding window join*.

Comment: HI Dieter yes like I said Obj and Log Tb's have same PI so why create DT's and I included logdate in my query , like you said - which was left out . But  actually the most costly step was joining with DBC. tables. I have to run the clock back on view point to get the exact  step level metric  ( nope we don't have step logging turned on ) but Here is a summary from the explain I took down`PDCRDATA.DBQLOBJTBL_HST = 42132 &  42130 ( built on all AMPS for the 2nd one  )  ;  DBC.DBASE 42137
42137 +42130=42138
This last step was costly and took 1.x hrs to run.

Comment: @user1874594: There's no join to dbc.tables in your query?

Comment: `JOIN dbc.children c   ON b.objectdatabasename=c.child`

Comment: Sorry for the typo I meant DBC tables as in plain English. I had'nt meant to qualify tables with DBC as db.

Comment: The other thing that's intrigues me is row disparity. I have 2 forms of the above Q that run well but the 1st form has 3 more rows than the 2nd one.The 2nd one give the exact o/p as the original Q.  But I am not able to fully understand why there is a disparity . This is the 1st form with 3 more rows

Comment: `SELECT
    b.objectdatabasename  ,
    a.username ,
    CAST( SUM((((a.AmpCPUTime(DEC(18,3)))+  ZEROIFNULL(a.ParserCPUTime)) )) AS DECIMAL(18,3)) (TITLE '')
   FROM pdcrinfo.dbqlogtbl a
  JOIN 
    (
    SELECT queryid,logdate,
        MIN (objectdatabasename) AS   o_nm
        FROM pdcrinfo.dbqlobjtbl_hst  
  where    o_nm in   ( sel  child  from  dbc.children where parent ='findb'  group by 1  )
        GROUP BY 1,2 )
           b ON  ( a.queryid=b.queryid 
  AND a.loGDATE=b.Logdate )
AND  a.logdate BETWEEN x and y
        and    b.logdate BETWEEN  x and y  GROUP BY 1, 2, 3`

Comment: compare that to the 2nd form . 'Course the SEL par is the same. Part that differs is `SEL...    FROM pdcrinfo.dbqlogtbl a
           JOIN 
    (
    SELECT queryid,logdate,
        MIN (objectdatabasename) AS                  objectdatabasename
        FROM pdcrinfo.dbqlobjtbl_hst
        GROUP BY 1,2 )
           b
 ON  ( a.queryid=b.queryid 
  AND a.loGDATE=b.Logdate )
AND  a.logdate BETWEEN   x and y 
        and    b.logdate BETWEEN  x and  y
where  b.objectdatabasename in   ( sel  child  from  dbc.children where parent ='findb'  group by 1  )
    GROUP BY 1,2 3`

Comment: I had another one that does not create any DT's that I used.  Joins Object and Log tables but I am leaning towards the DT form because like you said , what the MIN ( ObjectdataBaseName) was doing was removing the view db vs a table db for a specific queryID. e.g. `307194780443919933 1/10/2016 FINBASEVIEW1_T5
307194780443919933 1/10/2016 FINBASE_T5
` So it made sense that way , though in terms of metrics the non DT performed better ( < 7K CPU )

Comment: I used x and y as date range to save on chars so I can squeeze the comment within the character limit. The missing rows between the 1st and 2nd form are valid rows, that fall within  the scope of the query's intention. So it 'misses'  em .

Comment: As always ,Dieter ,Thanks a bunch for being responsive